# @Query for selecting date from datetime

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a JPA mapped "event" object that includes a timestamp column.  I am trying to select all events that occurred on a specific date.  To do this I need to ignore the time component of the timestamp.  I am not sure that this is possible using non database specific functions?  Something like this fails to select:

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM BioChemRequest r WHERE r.pasId = :pasid AND r.observationDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :startDate")
public List <BioChemRequest> find(@Param("pasid") String pasid , @Param("startDate") Date startDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM BioChemRequest r WHERE r.pasId = :pasid AND r.observationDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
public List <BioChemRequest> find(@Param("pasid") String pasid , @Param("startDate") Calendar startDate, @Param("endDate") Calendar endDate);
```

where startDate is a calendar with hour 00:00:00 000

and endDate is a calendar with hour 23:59:59 999

Comment: Perfect - thank you.  In fact it inspired me to convert the code to use LocalDateTime